Move from HTTP1 to HTTP2 in Nest js
I have a NestJS server currently using the HTTP/1 protocol. What steps do I need to take to upgrade my NestJS server to support HTTP/2? Is there built-in support for HTTP/2 in NestJS, or will I need to configure additional dependencies?
Here is my current setup:
async function bootstrap() {

    const httpsOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/secrets/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/secrets/server.crt'),
    };

    const nestLogger = new Logger('HTTP REQUEST');
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
        bufferLogs: true, 
        httpsOptions,
    });

    const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
    const corsUrl = configService.get<string>('CORS_URL').split(',');

    app.enableCors({
        origin: corsUrl,
        allowedHeaders: '*',
        methods: '*',
    });

    const morganFormat = ':method :url :status - :response-time ms';
    app.use(morgan(morganFormat, {
        stream: {
            write: (message: string) => {
                nestLogger.log(message.trim());
            },
        },
    }));
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "script-src 'self'");
        res.setHeader('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
        res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
        res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
        res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload');
        next();
    });

    await app.listen(8443);

    process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
        console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
    });

    process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
        console.error('Uncaught Exception:', error);
    });
}

bootstrap();


I tried implementing HTTP/2 using Express. Here’s what I did:
async function bootstrap() {
    const httpsOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/secrets/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/secrets/server.crt'),
    };

    const expressApp = require('express')();
    const app: NestExpressApplication = await NestFactory.create(
      AppModule,
      new ExpressAdapter(expressApp),
    );

    const corsUrl = process.env.CORS_URL?.split(',') || [];
    app.enableCors({
        origin: corsUrl,
        allowedHeaders: '*',
        methods: '*',
    });

    const nestLogger = new Logger('HTTP REQUEST');

    app.use(morgan(':method :url :status - :response-time ms', {
        stream: {
            write: (message: string) => nestLogger.log(message.trim()),
        },
    }));
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "script-src 'self'");
        res.setHeader('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
        res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
        res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
        res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload');
        next();
    });

    await app.init();

    const server = spdy.createServer(httpsOptions, expressApp);
    server.listen(8443, () => {
        console.log('Main Server is running on https://localhost:8443');
    });
}

async function startServers() {
    await bootstrap();
}

startServers();


When I log the request (req), it shows the HTTP/1 protocol, but in the browser's network tab, it shows the HTTP/2 protocol.
What am I missing here? Do I need to configure NestJS differently to fully support HTTP/2? Any advice would be appreciated!
